# Function syntax puzzler in scalaz

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-2.8, scalaz

Following watching [Nick Partidge's presentation](http://vimeo.com/10482466) on deriving [scalaz](http://github.com/scalaz/scalaz), I got to looking at this example, which is just awesome:

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
def even(x: Int) : Validation[NonEmptyList[String], Int] 
    = if (x % 2 ==0) x.success else "not even: %d".format(x).wrapNel.fail

println( even(3) <|*|> even(5) ) //prints: Failure(NonEmptyList(not even: 3, not even: 5))
```

I was trying to understand what the `<|*|>` method was doing, here is the source code:

```
def <|*|>[B](b: M[B])(implicit t: Functor[M], a: Apply[M]): M[(A, B)] 
    = <**>(b, (_: A, _: B))
```

OK, that is fairly confusing (!) - but it references the `<**>` method, which is declared thus:

```
def <**>[B, C](b: M[B], z: (A, B) => C)(implicit t: Functor[M], a: Apply[M]): M[C] 
    = a(t.fmap(value, z.curried), b)
```

So I have a few questions:

1. How come the method appears to take a *higher-kinded type* of one type parameter (`M[B]`) but can get passed a `Validation` (which has two type paremeters)?
2. The syntax `(_: A, _: B)` defines the function `(A, B) => Pair[A,B]` which the 2nd method expects: *what is happening to the Tuple2/Pair in the failure case? There's no tuple in sight!*

Comment: o_O  This is why, even in functional programming style, descriptive names of functions is good practice.

Comment: And what descriptive name would you suggest for this? I think that a symbolic name is much more preferable assuming it is consistent across the literature (e.g. FP papers)

Comment: Descriptive "names" are included. They are called "types". The best thing about these names are they are more robust, being machine checked, and give more information.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

#### Type Constructors as Type Parameters

`M` is a type parameter to one of Scalaz's main pimps, [MA](http://scalaz.googlecode.com/svn/continuous/latest/browse.sxr/scalaz/MA.scala.html), that represents the Type Constructor (aka Higher Kinded Type) of the pimped value. This type constructor is used to look up the appropriate instances of `Functor` and `Apply`, which are implicit requirements to the method `<**>`.

```
trait MA[M[_], A] {
   val value: M[A]
   def <**>[B, C](b: M[B], z: (A, B) => C)(implicit t: Functor[M], a: Apply[M]): M[C] = ...
}
```

#### What is a Type Constructor?

From the Scala Language Reference:

> We distinguish between first-order
>   types and type constructors, which
>   take type parameters and yield types.
>   A subset of first-order types called
>   value types represents sets of
>   (first-class) values. Value types are
>   either concrete or abstract. Every
>   concrete value type can be represented
>   as a class type, i.e. a type
>   designator (§3.2.3) that refers to a
>   class1 (§5.3), or as a compound type
>   (§3.2.7) representing an intersection
>   of types, possibly with a refinement
>   (§3.2.7) that further constrains the
>   types of itsmembers. Abstract value
>   types are introduced by type
>   parameters (§4.4) and abstract type
>   bindings (§4.3). Parentheses in types
>   are used for grouping. We assume that
>   objects and packages also implicitly
>   define a class (of the same name as
>   the object or package, but
>   inaccessible to user programs).
>
> Non-value types capture properties of
>   identifiers that are not values
>   (§3.3). For example, a type
>   constructor (§3.3.3) does not directly
>   specify the type of values. However,
>   when a type constructor is applied to
>   the correct type arguments, it yields
>   a first-order type, which may be a
>   value type. Non-value types are
>   expressed indirectly in Scala. E.g., a
>   method type is described by writing
>   down a method signature, which in
>   itself is not a real type, although it
>   gives rise to a corresponding function
>   type (§3.3.1). Type constructors are
>   another example, as one can write type
>   Swap[m[_, _], a,b] = m[b, a], but
>   there is no syntax to write the
>   corresponding anonymous type function
>   directly.

`List` is a type constructor. You can apply the type `Int` to get a Value Type, `List[Int]`, which can classify a value. Other type constructors take more than one parameter.

The trait `scalaz.MA` requires that it's first type parameter must be a type constructor that takes a single type to return a value type, with the syntax `trait MA[M[_], A] {}`. The type parameter definition describes the shape of the type constructor, which is referred to as its Kind. `List` is said to have the kind '`* -> *`.

#### Partial Application of Types

But how can `MA` wrap a values of type `Validation[X, Y]`? The type `Validation` has a kind `(* *) -> *`, and could only be passed as a type argument to a type parameter declared like `M[_, _]`.

This implicit conversion in [object Scalaz](http://scalaz.googlecode.com/svn/continuous/latest/browse.sxr/scalaz/Scalaz.scala.html#22849) converts a value of type `Validation[X, Y]` to a `MA`:

```
object Scalaz {
    implicit def ValidationMA[A, E](v: Validation[E, A]): MA[PartialApply1Of2[Validation, E]#Apply, A] = ma[PartialApply1Of2[Validation, E]#Apply, A](v)
}
```

Which in turn uses a trick with a type alias in [PartialApply1Of2](http://scalaz.googlecode.com/svn/continuous/latest/browse.sxr/scalaz/PartialApply1Of2.scala.html) to partially apply the type constructor `Validation`, fixing the type of the errors, but leaving the type of the success unapplied.

`PartialApply1Of2[Validation, E]#Apply` would be better written as `[X] => Validation[E, X]`. I recently proposed to add such a syntax to Scala, it might happen in 2.9.

Think of this as a type level equivalent of this:

```
def validation[A, B](a: A, b: B) = ...
def partialApply1Of2[A, B C](f: (A, B) => C, a: A): (B => C) = (b: B) => f(a, b)
```

This lets you combine `Validation[String, Int]` with a `Validation[String, Boolean]`, because the both share the type constructor `[A] Validation[String, A]`.

#### Applicative Functors

`<**>` demands the the type constructor `M` must have associated instances of [Apply](http://scalaz.googlecode.com/svn/continuous/latest/browse.sxr/scalaz/Apply.scala.html) and [Functor](http://scalaz.googlecode.com/svn/continuous/latest/browse.sxr/scalaz/Functor.scala.html). This constitutes an Applicative Functor, which, like a Monad, is a way to structure a computation through some effect. In this case the effect is that the sub-computations can fail (and when they do, we accumulate the failures).

The container `Validation[NonEmptyList[String], A]` can wrap a pure value of type `A` in this 'effect'. The `<**>` operator takes two effectful values, and a pure function, and combines them with the Applicative Functor instance for that container.

Here's how it works for the `Option` applicative functor. The 'effect' here is the possibility of failure.

```
val os: Option[String] = Some("a")
val oi: Option[Int] = Some(2)

val result1 = (os <**> oi) { (s: String, i: Int) => s * i }
assert(result1 == Some("aa"))

val result2 = (os <**> (None: Option[Int])) { (s: String, i: Int) => s * i }
assert(result2 == None)
```

In both cases, there is a pure function of type `(String, Int) => String`, being applied to effectful arguments. Notice that the result is wrapped in the same effect (or container, if you like), as the arguments.

You can use the same pattern across a multitude of containers that have an associated Applicative Functor. All Monads are automatically Applicative Functors, but there are even more, like `ZipStream`.

`Option` and `[A]Validation[X, A]` are both Monads, so you could also used `Bind` (aka flatMap):

```
val result3 = oi flatMap { i => os map { s => s * i } }
val result4 = for {i <- oi; s <- os} yield s * i
```

#### Tupling with `<|**|>`

`<|**|>` is really similar to `<**>`, but it provides the pure function for you to simply build a Tuple2 from the results. `(_: A, _ B)` is a shorthand for `(a: A, b: B) => Tuple2(a, b)`

#### And beyond

Here's our bundled examples for [Applicative](http://scalaz.googlecode.com/svn/continuous/latest/browse.sxr/scalaz/example/ExampleApplicative.scala.html) and [Validation](http://scalaz.googlecode.com/svn/continuous/latest/browse.sxr/scalaz/example/ExampleValidation.scala.html). I used a slightly different syntax to use the Applicative Functor, `(fa ⊛ fb ⊛ fc ⊛ fd) {(a, b, c, d) => .... }`

#### UPDATE: But what happens in the Failure Case?

> *what is happening to the Tuple2/Pair in the failure case*?

If any of the sub-computations fails, the provided function is never run. It only is run if all sub-computations (in this case, the two arguments passed to `<**>`) are successful. If so, it combines these into a `Success`. Where is this logic? This defines the `Apply` instance for `[A] Validation[X, A]`. We require that the type X must have a `Semigroup` avaiable, which is the strategy for combining the individual errors, each of type `X`, into an aggregated error of the same type. If you choose `String` as your error type, the `Semigroup[String]` concatenates the strings; if you choose `NonEmptyList[String]`, the error(s) from each step are concatenated into a longer `NonEmptyList` of errors. This concatenation happens below when two `Failures` are combined, using the `⊹` operator (which expands with implicits to, for example, `Scalaz.IdentityTo(e1).⊹(e2)(Semigroup.NonEmptyListSemigroup(Semigroup.StringSemigroup))`.

```
implicit def ValidationApply[X: Semigroup]: Apply[PartialApply1Of2[Validation, X]#Apply] = new Apply[PartialApply1Of2[Validation, X]#Apply] {
  def apply[A, B](f: Validation[X, A => B], a: Validation[X, A]) = (f, a) match {
    case (Success(f), Success(a)) => success(f(a))
    case (Success(_), Failure(e)) => failure(e)
    case (Failure(e), Success(_)) => failure(e)
    case (Failure(e1), Failure(e2)) => failure(e1 ⊹ e2)
  }
}
```

#### Monad or Applicative, how shall I choose?

Still reading? (*Yes. Ed*)

I've shown that sub-computations based on `Option` or `[A] Validation[E, A]` can be combined with either `Apply` or with `Bind`. When would you choose one over the other?

When you use `Apply`, the structure of the computation is fixed. All sub-computations will be executed; the results of one can't influence the the others. Only the 'pure' function has an overview of what happened. Monadic computations, on the other hand, allow the first sub-computation to influence the later ones.

If we used a Monadic validation structure, the first failure would short-circuit the entire validation, as there would be no `Success` value to feed into the subsequent validation. However, we are happy for the sub-validations to be independent, so we can combine them through the Applicative, and collect all the failures we encounter. The weakness of Applicative Functors has become a strength!

Comment: I sahould not have used the word "monad": apologies. I realize that `M[_]` is describing a *higher-kinded type*. I've edited the question now

Comment: Really nice and detailed answer.

Comment: I edited the answer accordingly to focus on type constructors and applicative functors, rather than the absense of monads :)

Comment: Wow, you are my favourite person.

Comment: Now, hurry and go write a book!

Comment: I read that answer today and it was very helpful to me too, thanks!