# Scalaz: request for use case for Cokleisli composition

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-2.8, scalaz

This question isn't meant as flame-bait! As it might be apparent, I've been looking at [Scalaz](http://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) recently. I'm trying to understand *why* I need some of the functionality that the library provides. Here's something:

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
type NEL[A] = NonEmptyList[A]
val NEL = NonEmptyList
```

I put some println statements in my functions to see what was going on (*aside: what would I have done if I was trying to avoid side effects like that?*). My functions are:

```
val f: NEL[Int] => String    = (l: NEL[Int]) => {println("f: " + l); l.toString |+| "X" }
val g: NEL[String] => BigInt = (l: NEL[String]) => {println("g: " + l);  BigInt(l.map(_.length).sum) }
```

Then I combine them via a **cokleisli** and pass in a `NEL[Int]`

```
val k = cokleisli(f) =>= cokleisli(g)
println("RES: "  + k( NEL(1, 2, 3) ))
```

What does this print?

```
f: NonEmptyList(1, 2, 3)
f: NonEmptyList(2, 3)
f: NonEmptyList(3)
g: NonEmptyList(NonEmptyList(1, 2, 3)X, NonEmptyList(2, 3)X, NonEmptyList(3)X)
RES: 57
```

The RES value is the character count of the (String) elements in the final NEL. Two things occur to me:

1. How could I have known that my NEL was going to be reduced in this manner from the method signatures involved? (I wasn't expecting the result *at all*)
2. What is the point of this? Can a reasonably simple and easy-to-follow use case be distilled for me?

This question is a thinly-veiled plea for some lovely person like *[retronym](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545248/function-syntax-puzzler-in-scalaz/2546400#2546400)* to explain how this powerful library actually works.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To understand the result, you need to understand the `Comonad[NonEmptyList]` instance. `Comonad[W]` essentially provides three functions (the actual interface in Scalaz is a little different, but this helps with explanation):

```
map:    (A => B) => W[A] => W[B]
copure: W[A] => A
cojoin: W[A] => W[W[A]]
```

So, `Comonad` provides an interface for some container `W` that has a distinguished "head" element (`copure`) and a way of exposing the inner structure of the container so that we get one container per element (`cojoin`), each with a given element at the head.

The way that this is implemented for `NonEmptyList` is that `copure` returns the head of the list, and `cojoin` returns a list of lists, with this list at the head and all tails of this list at the tail.

Example (I'm shortening `NonEmptyList` to `Nel`):

```
Nel(1,2,3).copure = 1
Nel(1,2,3).cojoin = Nel(Nel(1,2,3),Nel(2,3),Nel(3))
```

The `=>=` function is coKleisli composition. How would you compose two functions `f: W[A] => B` and `g: W[B] => C`, knowing nothing about them other than that `W` is a `Comonad`? The input type of `f` and the output type of `g` aren't compatible. However, you can `map(f)` to get `W[W[A]] => W[B]` and then compose that with `g`. Now, given a `W[A]`, you can `cojoin` it to get the `W[W[A]]` to feed into that function. So, the only reasonable composition is a function `k` that does the following:

```
k(x) = g(x.cojoin.map(f))
```

So for your nonempty list:

```
g(Nel(1,2,3).cojoin.map(f))
= g(Nel(Nel(1,2,3),Nel(2,3),Nel(3)).map(f))
= g(Nel("Nel(1,2,3)X","Nel(2,3)X","Nel(3)X"))
= BigInt(Nel("Nel(1,2,3)X","Nel(2,3)X","Nel(3)X").map(_.length).sum)
= BigInt(Nel(11,9,7).sum)
= 27
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer - I've accepted *retronym's* because he has answered the request for a use case but this one is still great!

Comment: No sweat, I've edited retronym's answer to add a cokleisli composition example.

Comment: I believe you ment "you can `map(f)` to get `W[W[A]] => W[B]`", alas I do not have editing rights.

Answer (score 9):

Cojoin is also defined for [scalaz.Tree](http://scalaz.googlecode.com/svn/continuous/latest/browse.sxr/scalaz/Tree.scala.html#12387) and [scalaz.TreeLoc](http://scalaz.googlecode.com/svn/continuous/latest/browse.sxr/scalaz/TreeLoc.scala.html#12453). This can be [exploited](http://scalaz.googlecode.com/svn/continuous/latest/browse.sxr/scalaz/example/ExampleTree.scala.html#13383) to find a stream of all paths from the root of the tree to each leaf node.

```
def leafPaths[T](tree: Tree[T]): Stream[Stream[T]]
  = tree.loc.cojoin.toTree.flatten.filter(_.isLeaf).map(_.path)
```

Using coKleisli arrow composition, we can do this, for example:

```
def leafDist[A] = (cokleisli(leafPaths[A]) &&& cokleisli(_.rootLabel))
  =>= (_.map(s => (s._2, s._1.map(_.length).max)))
```

`leafDist` takes a Tree and returns a copy of it with each node annotated with its maximum distance from a leaf.