# Scala partially applied type constructor inference

Tags: scala, type-inference, scalaz

I'm using **scala-2.8.1** and **scalaz-5.0**. Can anyone explain exactly why a `PartialApply1Of2` can be inferrred in the one case but not in the other?

```
scala> 1.success[String] <|*|> "Bah".fail[Int]
res1: scalaz.Validation[String,(Int, Int)] = Failure(Bah)
```

That worked even though ([as has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545248/function-syntax-puzzler-in-scalaz)!) the method `<|*|>` is on `MA` which has one type parameter, not two (as `Validation` has). I cannot get unicode working in my IDEA REPL, so here goes:

```
object testy {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    import scalaz._
    import Scalaz._
    val ps = NonEmptyList(1.success[String], "Bah".fail[Int])

    val res = ps.∘∘((_ : Int) % 2 == 0) //DOES NOT COMPILE
    println(res)
  }
}
```

I can provide a specific type to the call and all is good. Why can `scalac` not infer this?

```
ps.∘∘[PartialApply1Of2[Validation, String]#Apply, Int, Boolean]((_ : Int) % 2 == 0)
```

In my REPL, this actually causes a scalac error, rather than a sensible error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, the implicit view `ValidationMA` is inferred, and the the type argument `Int` is inferred:

```
Scalaz.ValidationMA(1.success[String]).<|*|>[Int]("Bah".fail[Int])
```

In the second case, the type argument to the method `∘∘` cannot be inferred, until [#2712](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/2712) is tackled.

I suspect that the scalac internal error you encountered is related to [#2741](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/2741) / [#4079](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/2741). If so, you can rewrite it with a Type Lambda to workaround the error.

```
ps.∘∘[({type X[a]=Validation[String, a]})#X, Int, Boolean]((_ : Int) % 2 == 0)
```

I recommend using this syntax instead of `PartialApplyNofM` in all cases, as I find it more readable. With a recent build of IntelliJ, you can even enable a code folding (Settings, Code Style, Scala, Folding, Type Lambas), to [hide some syntactic clutter](http://twitpic.com/3foo8x/full).